# Unable to query 58 MB file in athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am trying to query files in `S3` (57 MB) using `ATHENA` but `athena` is returning only `column` names not any `record`. I have created a table using `aws` glue crawler . I am not able to figure out this as I am new to AWS.

Comment: What kind of data are you querying? S3 access logs?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is insufficient information in your Question for us to be able to assist you. Can you please Edit your question to provide more information? For example, can you show the `CREATE TABLE` statement that was used to create the table, and some sample lines of data from the S3 files? Also, please let us know how you created the table (eg was it via an AWS Glue crawler, or was it hand-crafted)?

Comment: I have created table using aws glue crawler.

Comment: Please provide some sample data from the file in S3. Also provide the output of "show create table <tablename>" command from athena console.